# XPI of SDK Add-on that has all modules

Tags: firefox-addon-sdk

People post some simple questions in the firefox-addon-sdk. I know nothing about sdk but can still answer it. I just need to be able to test things on the fly.

The way I usually test things is scratchpad. If I need bootstrap scope then I have a dummy on my github, I just edit the bootstrap.js and don't need to commit/save, just type in that text box and hit install with the GitHub Extension Installer addon and then it runs.

Now I want to do the same for addon-sdk addons. I need like a blank sdk addon that has everything in it. Lots of times in main.js I paste some code someone wants me to test and it fails because the xpi doesn't have the right authority.

Is there a link to a master xpi that is a sdk addon with everything in it but blank main.js?

Comment: I still don't really understand your use case. What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: Like the other day some guy posted how to test if the contents of the array returned by `list` are file or directory. When I copied and pasted his code into main.js of a addon sdk i had on my repo i get permission errors when requiring the modules, like their missing or something. So I couldnt run his code to `console.log` the list and see what was in it.

Comment: ...but, all the SDK modules are shipped in Firefox. I think you had a different problem.

Comment: Oh maybe i used an old sdk version addon. Ill try another addon.